Rattling noise when accelerating
I have a Ford KA Edge 2010 with rattling coming from the rear left (I think) when accelerating. Slight loss of power. Timing belt done 3 years ago and new exhaust system 3 years ago.
Is this a loose exhaust issue? Oil is topped up along with other fluids.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine is in your KA? How many miles on it? Is this something new, or has it been happening for a while?

1.2 engine, 77,000 miles and been happening for a week

I'm wondering if you might have a loose heat shield. It may be body mounted or part of the exhaust itself, but would be found somewhere along the route of the exhaust.
